# Laravel can't add foreign key even if assigned as unsigned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, migration

I have a table named `choices` and I want the `choice_id` to be primary key BUT not auto increment because I got a seeder for it.

Here is my migration for `choices`

```
     Schema::create('choices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('choice_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('choice');
            $table->integer('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('choices',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('question_id')
                    ->references('question_id')
                    ->on('questions');
        });
```

Also, here is for the answers

```
     Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('choice_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('answers',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('question_id')
                    ->references('question_id')
                    ->on('questions');

            $table->foreign('choice_id')
                    ->references('choice_id')
                    ->on('choices');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('user_id')
                    ->on('schedules');
        });
```

When I do migrate I got

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 
1005 Can't create table
`scheduler`.`answers` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
(SQL: alter table `answers` add constraint
`answers_choice_id_foreign` foreign key (`choice_id`) references `choices` (`choice_id`))

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1005 Can't create table `scheduler`.`answers` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

Comment: You didn't add `unsigned` to the choice_id in `choices`, so it may not match the choice_id in answers.

Comment: even if i put `$table->bigInteger('choice_id')->unsigned();` in `choices` i got the same error sir @aynber

Comment: Now `choice_id` in `choices` is a `bigInteger`, but `choice_id` in `answers` is just `integer`. Those should match. (and not a sir)

Comment: its the same I changed it to `$table->bigInteger('choice_id')->unsigned();` still get the same error. I dont know why is this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've matched the types up, the reason it's failing is the other key isn't indexed, a foreign key creates an index in the table but it also needs one in the other table.

Put the following in your choices migration:

```
$table->bigInteger('choice_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change type of `choice_id` in `choices` table to big increments.